# How do I get tmux to open up a set of panes without manually entering them?

Tags: tmux

So, I want to make a project-specific `tmux` session that pops up certain commands in certain panes automagically.  Following an [online tutorial](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux) and the `tmux` man page, this is what I come up with for a configuration file:

```
new -n estruct ls
neww -n estruct2 ls
splitw -v -p 50 -t 0 ls
```

The result is ... nothing.  `tmux` starts up with a single window and single pane in that window with no commands executed.

How would I go about making a configuration file that actually allows me to create a set of windows and panes with certain commands pre-executed?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your configuration file is working, but there are a couple of complications.

## Short-lived Commands

First, the commands you are starting (instances of *ls*) finish running very quickly. The windows and panes for the commands are created, but they disappear as soon as each command exits.

If your goal is to actually use such “one shot” commands in your eventual configuration, then you should probably use the window option `remain-on-exit` (and possibly the session option `set-remain-on-exit` to provide a default for all windows created in the session). When `remain-on-exit` is set for a window, it will not disappear when the command exits. You will probably want to map the `respawn-window` to a key (note: `respawn-window` will respawn the original command; `respawn-pane` is also available in *tmux* 1.5 to respawn individual panes).

```
bind-key R respawn-window

# set global r-o-e so that initial window of initial session gets it
set -g set-remain-on-exit on

# create a session and its windows/panes
new -n estruct ls
neww -n estruct2 ls
splitw -v -p 50 -t 0 ls

# restore global r-o-e
set -g set-remain-on-exit off

# let session r-o-e inherit from global value for future windows
set -u set-remain-on-exit
```

Or, if you do not mind your initial window being number 1 instead of number 0, then we can avoid changing the global value:

```
bind-key R respawn-window

# create a session with a throw-away window
new true

# for future windows, stay open after the command exits
set set-remain-on-exit on

# create the windows we really want
neww -n estruct ls
neww -n estruct2 ls
splitw -v -p 50 -t 0 ls

# for future windows, revert r-o-e to global value
set -u set-remain-on-exit
```

If you were only using `ls` as a simplified placeholder command and you actually intend to spawn some type of interactive command in your windows/panes, then you should probably just spawn the command you intended to eventually run. If your intended command takes too long to startup to use it during *tmux* testing, then substitute a shell or other simple interactive command (e.g. `top`, `sqlite3`, etc.).

## `new-session` Is the Default Command

Second, running *tmux* without a command argument (e.g. `tmux`) is equivalent to using the `new-session` command (i.e. `tmux` is the same as `tmux new-session`). Your `.tmux.conf` creates a session for its windows/panes (`new` is an alias for `new-session`) and another session is being created for the implicit `new-session` command specified by starting *tmux* without a command argument. If you are using the default status bar, you will see a `[1]` in the left side of the status bar when you are in the “extra” session (the initial session created in the `.tmux.conf` is number 0).

If you want to avoid creating the extra session, then use `tmux attach` instead of plain `tmux`. The commands from your `.tmux.conf` will run, creating session 0, and then your client will attach to that session instead of creating a new one.

Comment: OK, I'm maybe being as thick as a whale sandwich here, but right now I've got a configuration file that has only `splitw` in it -- nothing else -- and I'm still not getting a split screen because it says it can't establish the current session.  If I add `new` before it, I get ... one window, one pane.  I can't seem, for the life of me to get two panes at start-up.

Comment: A config file with `new`, then `splitw` works for me when I start *tmux* via `tmux attach`. One thing to remember is that the `.tmux.conf` (or the file specified with the `-f` option) is only used if there is no server already running. Check whether a server is running via `tmux ls`. If you want to run the commands from a file when a server is already running, then do it like this: `tmux source-file /path/to/conf-file-that-creates-a-session-and-windows \; attach` (if you run this when there is no server your `.tmux.conf` (or the `-f` file) will run first then your `source-file` file).

Comment: The config file is being specified with -f -- so I'm going `tmux new -f myconfig`.  The contents of that config file contains **only** `new` followed by `splitw`.  I am killing any and all tmux processes before I try the command line `tmux -f myconfig`.  I don't get two panes.  I'm really at a loss here with what to do past this point (aside from just giving up on tmux).

Comment: @Just: Whether you use `-f` or not, `tmux` without a command argument is the same as `tmux new-session` (which, for new servers, will create a new session on top of whatever your config file does). Your pre-split window is created in session 0, but the implicit `new-session` command is creating (and attaching to) an extra session (session 1; look for the `[1]` in your status line). Use `tmux -f myconfig attach` to avoid creating the new session that is hiding your pre-split window.

Comment: OK, I guess learning to read will eventually pay off for me.  :)  Thanks for the effort and the answer.  Everything's working fine now.  I wish there was a reputation "tipping jar" here so I could give you more than just an accepted answer.

Comment: "Thick as a whale sandwich"  +1

Comment: My god, how did this answer not get upvoted?  +1

Comment: respawn-pane is already present in my homebrew tmux 1.5

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "manually entering", but this is how I do it.  I wrote an "autostart" script that my window manager launches.  It contains:

```
tmux start-server                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
for i in ~/sessions_tmux/*.session; do "$i"; done
```

where each .session file looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

SESSION_NAME="flaskr_tutorial"
if [[ ! -z "$TMUX" ]] || [[ ! -z "$TMUX_PANE" ]]; then
    echo "Already inside a tmux session, do not know what to do"
    exit 1
fi
tmux -q has-session -t "$SESSION_NAME"
if [ $? ]; then
    exit 0
fi
NEWCWD=~/projects/flaskr/
( cd "${NEWCWD}"; tmux new-session -d -s "$SESSION_NAME" )
tmux send-keys -t "$SESSION_NAME" 'vim flaskr.py' Enter
( cd "${NEWCWD}"; tmux split -h -t "$SESSION_NAME" )
tmux send-keys -t "$SESSION_NAME" 'sudo tail -F -n 100 /var/log/messages | ccze' Enter
```

Wait, there's more!  I have an ever growing number of .session files that I load up with konsole:

```
konsole --background-mode --profile Shell --tabs-from-file ~/sessions_tmux/work_console.tabs
```

where work_console.tabs looks something like this:

```
.
.
.
title: projectx;;    command: tmux attach -t projectx
title: flaskr;;      command: tmux attach -t flaskr_tutorial
.
.
.
```

Then I press F12 to launch konsole.

Comment: konsole seems to be broken so I've switched to [Terminal](http://www.xfce.org/projects/terminal/), which works well. I have a more detailed [post](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=29900965) on the tmux-users mailing list.

Comment: Just a small comment, you can replace '! -z' with '-n' in your tests ;)

Answer (score 7):

suppose you want to launch 3 server monitoring tasks (here ping localhost)  there's no need to mess with configuration files and saved sessions. It can all be done from the command-line.

```
tmux new-session 'ping  127.0.0.1' \; \
    split-window 'ping  127.0.0.1' \; \
    split-window 'ping  127.0.0.1' \; \
    select-layout even-vertical
```

Comment: Thanks for the simplicity - exactly the example I was looking for!

Answer (score 5):

I found [teamocil](http://remiprev.github.com/teamocil/) very useful for automating tmux windows/sessions.

Its written in Ruby so you need that installed.

Here is a sample configuration:

```
session:
  name: 'my project'
  windows:
    -name: vim
     root: '~/code/my_project'
     splits:
       - cmd: vim
       - cmd: guard
```

You can have an arrangement of windows and splits.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative similar to teamcoil is [tmuxinator](https://github.com/aziz/tmuxinator), it's on active development and works quite well. It's also recommended (and kind of reviewed) on the amazing [tmux: Productive Mouse-Free Development](http://pragprog.com/book/bhtmux/tmux) from [The Pragmatic Bookshelf](http://www.pragprog.com).

Comment: Found it a tad bit cleaner than teamocil (but very similar nonetheless) and am using it right now. I'm pretty happy with how it works!

Answer (score 4):

**

- ### Better Save your Session !

**
I found that for a lazy admin like myself, I would rather save the session of tmux, rather than spending hours trying to build it perfectly. 
I am administering more than 30 servers, and my tmux sessions are dynamic, with configiuration changing all the time. 
It was pain in the neck, till I recently discovered [tmux-resurrect](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect)
this plugin is just great. Give it a try.
Currently, Ubuntu repositories have tmux 1.8, this plugin needs 1.9, so you would need to upgrade manually

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pi-rho/dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install  tmux=2.0-1~ppa1~t
```

After which you can install it by

```
git clone https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect ~/clone/path
```

Then dd this line to the bottom of ~/.tmux.conf (if ~/.tmux.conf is not available, create an empty file)

```
run-shell ~/clone/path/resurrect.tmux
```

I also add this line at the end of the ~/.tmux.conf so that the plugin saves sessions for all programs I run

```
set -g @resurrect-processes ':all:'
```

Then reload tmux environment.

```
tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

That's it! You are done. Now, run tmux as normal, resize your panes, create new panes, create new sessions...etc. When you are happy with the configuration you reached ( in several windows and several sessions), just click ctrl+b then ctrl+s to save the session.
In order to test the results, just kill all tmux

```
killall tmux
```

Then, run again tmux

```
tmux
```

Then, from within tmux click ctrl+b then ctrl+r (for restore)
Magically, all your windows, panes, and sessions are restored with the same geometry and arrangement.
Hope that this would help.